# Some problems with MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Huge amount of TIME_WAIT connections says netstat](https://serverfault.com/questions/23385/huge-amount-of-time-wait-connections-says-netstat)

I have 2167 connections like that:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:34276             127.0.0.1:3306              TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:34910             127.0.0.1:3306              TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306              127.0.0.1:42749             TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:34871             127.0.0.1:3306              TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:34845             127.0.0.1:3306              TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:34018             127.0.0.1:3306              TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:35336             127.0.0.1:3306              TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:34617             127.0.0.1:3306              TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306              127.0.0.1:33750             TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:34072             127.0.0.1:3306              TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:34141             127.0.0.1:3306              TIME_WAIT

[root@saritasa semenov]# netstat -an | grep 127.0.0.1 | grep 3306 | wc
1360    8160  121040
```

Any ideas why and how can I resolve it?

Mysql SHOW PROCESSLIST; does give me just 5 connections. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lower the following

```
 /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fin_timeout
```

You have so many due it being a security feature for tcp. I forget all the details I just know  what the end reason for it was. It's not a big deal to have a lot of time wait's at all